# Python3 scapy failed to get the MAC address

Tags: scapy

I am learning "Python Black Hat". I will not respond when I use scapy to get the IP address of ip. I have not received any reply from the sent packet. I found a simple example from the Internet and the effect is the same. Why is that?

```
from scapy.all import srp,Ether,ARP,conf
ipscan='127.0.0.1'
try:
   ans,unans=
srp(Ether(dst="FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF")/ARP(pdst=ipscan),timeout=2,verbose=False)
except Exception as e:
print(str(e))
else:
  for snd,rcv in ans:
    list_mac=rcv.sprintf("%Ether.src% - %ARP.psrc%")
    print(list_mac)
```

I learned ARP spoofing in the book, experimented with my win7 virtual machine, but failed to get the MAC address.

Comment: I would say you need to use a net range as ipscan. For instance, `192.168.0.1/24` (if your network up really is 192.168.0.x)

Comment: My IP address is in the range of 192.168.155.1/24. I have tried to specify the range of ipscan before, but the effect is still the same. The 256 packets sent out are not responding.

Answer (score 1):

Since every network interface only answer for address that bound to them and You're sending your packet to yourself (127.0.0.1), nobody answer your request. change the ipscan then it works fine

Comment: My IP address is in the range of 192.168.155.1/24. I have tried to specify the range of ipscan before, but the effect is still the same. The 256 packets sent out are not responding.

Comment: If you set a correct IP range like 192.168.155.0/24 or a specific IP like 192.168.155.1 and still getting NOTHING, then it's not your code, because I checked and it works fine, it's in your network settings. you're missing something.